# How can I add extra textbox in with default textboxs in CreateUserwizard in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, createuserwizard

I want to add extra textbox in CreateUserwizard control as given below:

```
<CreateUserWizard        ID="CreateUserWizard1">
--------- Default             attributes start here----------
Name: <asp:TextBox ID =     NameText />
Address: <asp:TextBox ID =  AddressText />
Email: <asp:TextBox ID =     EmailText />
Password: <asp:TextBox ID = PasswordText />
-----------Default         attributes end here------------
-----------Custom attributes start here---------
Location: <asp:TextBox ID =    LocationText />
------------Custom attributes end here---------
</CreateUserWizard>
```

First four fields are default, I want to add one extra textbox Location. I have tried as possible as I can, but could not success.

Please Guide me, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please specify what you have tried so far and where and why you failed. What error do you get? What does not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Well, as noted, you do need to provide some markup and what you have so far.

However, there is VERY little reason to use the CreateUser wizard if you looking to build your own, or change it.

Furthermore, quite sure the CreateUserWizard ONLY works with what we call WebFroms and FBA. (forms based authnetication).

There is VERY little advantage and VERY little reason to use the createUserWizard, and you are free to drop in your own text boxes, and when you hit createuser, you can simple add that row to the user datbase.

Do you have that user database setup working?

Have you added the extra columns to that database for the new extra "custom" fields/columns you want? (you need to do this).

All the create user does is take some inputs from some textboxes on the web page, and when you hit create user, it adds the one new row to the user database.

So, it makes LITTLE sense to start asking about the createuser wizard when we don't know if you have the user database working, don't know if you added the extra new columns to that database.

However, I suggest you do NOT use nor care about using that built-in CreateUser wizard. You can just drop in some controls (text boxes), and your own button, and the click event for the create user can simple add that one new row to the user database.

So, the "instant" you want to customize that create user wizard, in most cases, you are better off to simple create your own markup, and just code it out. it is not much more work, but MORE important, you have better and full control over the fields and and extra new information you want when adding a new user to the table used for logons.

Worse yet? You don't mention or even note if you have the built-in Createuser wizard working?

In other words, does the createuserwizard EVEN WORK for you right now, and does it correctly add new users to the table you are using for users? I mean, it makes VERY little sense to ask about customizing the create user wizard when you not even make it clear that it works now?

so, I recommend you do NOT use the CreateUserWizard, and it is PAINFULL to customize anyway, and it not all that flexible anyway. Worse yet, it really does not help you much at all compared to just dropping some plain jane text boxes, and a button to build your own "custom" create user page anyway.

Do you have the create user working now? Does it correctly add new users to the users table you are using in the database? Without knowing this information, we really can't help you much.